# Как установить fullPath из $route в качестве значениия атрибута в шаблоне на Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, route, bootstrap-vue

Здравсвуйте!

В Nuxt.js надо сделать кнопку, и присвоить ей URL основанный на текущем URL. Ни как не пойму как вытащить из $route fullpath и использовать его для сборки URL для кнопки.

Т.е. есть $route, см. через Vue DevTools:

```
$route {
    "path":"/admin/companies/25",
    "query":{},
    "params":{"id":"25"},
    "fullPath":"/admin/companies/25",
    "name":"admin-companies-id",
    "meta":{}
}
```

В шаблоне этой страницы присутствует строка с кнопкой(Bootstrap-Vue):

```
<b-btn class="ml-1" variant="dark" to="URL">Создать</b-btn>
```

Вместо to="URL" в кнопке надо получить

```
to="/admin/companies/25/reports/create"
```

Ни как не пойму, как обратиться к $route.fullPath, чтобы присвоить его значение атрибуту to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется нашел, необходимо использовать директиву v-bind:

```
v-bind:to="$route.fullPath + '/reports/create'"
```

или

```
:to="$route.fullPath + '/reports/create'"
```